# OkHttp Android stream was reset: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED

Tags: android, azure, okhttp, http2, azure-app-service-plans

We are developing an Android application that should use Http/2 to connect to our Azure App Service.
On the Azure App Service we have Http/2 enabled by using the steps in the following blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/13/announcing-http2-support-in-azure-app-service/

Our requests are secured with Mutual SSL, so that the application has to send it's client certificate.

When we try to execute a call to our app service with OkHttp, we always get the following error and stacktrace. When we try to do a call to the twitter api with the same Android code, this is working.

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

We are using OkHttp version 3.10.0.

Stacktrace:

```
    06-08 15:54:00.173 31318-31351/be.wgkovl.evdt W/be.wgkovl.evdt.utils.BaseService: stream was reset: HTTP_1_1_REQUIREDokhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED
                at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:153) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:125) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) ~[na:0.0]
                at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77) ~[na:0.0]
                at be.wgkovl.evdt.utils.BaseService.executeRequest(BaseService.java:277) ~[na:0.0]
                at be.wgkovl.evdt.service.UserManagementService$1.doInBackground(UserManagementService.java:123) ~[na:0.0]
                at be.wgkovl.evdt.service.UserManagementService$1.doInBackground(UserManagementService.java:101) ~[na:0.0]
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) ~[na:0.0]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) ~[na:0.0]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) ~[na:0.0]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) ~[na:0.0]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) ~[na:0.0]
```

Answer (score 16):

add this line in builder

```
.protocols(Util.immutableList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
```

like this

```
 private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .protocols(Util.immutableList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP/2 does not really support client certificates at this time - especially when such connections only apply to some of the resources on the server. There is [a proposal to allow this](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-secondary-certs-01.html), but it is not yet standardised and, AFAIK, not yet supported by any implementation.

Until this is supported, [the correct response is to suggest a downgrade to HTTP/1.1](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#n-tls-1.2-features) with a HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED error code and the client should retry with HTTP/1.1.

[Other implementations](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=33810) do this as well as Azure.

Comment: This is odd. Because when I connect to my Azure endpoint with client certificate using the Edge browser. It is correctly returning a response and I see that HTTP/2 is used with the network monitor...
This would mean it supports client certificate.

Comment: Extra information: the client certificates do apply to every resource on the server. Not only to specific endpoints.